# is it possible to play m3u8 video in google chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, windows-7, html5-video

Is there any way via extension / hack / or otherwise to play an m3u8 video from google chrome?  I'm having some trouble getting the official word on m3u8 support, though I'm pretty sure its unsupported.

I'm working on a video player with live playback (using flash for standard browser apps) so I'm using m3u8's to get everything working on mobile, but the debugging tools on mobile leave a lot to be desired.  I was wondering if there was any workaround to getting these videos to work so I could use the browser debuggers.  (I'm on windows 7).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a new [appendBytes/sourceBuffer proposal](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/html-media/raw-file/tip/media-source/media-source.html#source-buffer-model) in the spec, and I saw a chrome evangelist mention that there was a beta implementation in chrome canary. With that you would have to write a ton of javascript to read the m3u8 file, get the video segments, parse the data, and push them into the media element manually. I'm guessing that's more than you want to do for testing.

What you probably want is something like [Weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/).